# MVC Reroute to accept Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

working on an MVC project and I'm having a tough time with rerouting my URL. 
What I currently have is

http://dev.mywebsite.com/s/index?Key=abc123

which then runs the index action and completes as I'd like it to
I'd like to be able to type in

http://dev.mywebsite.com/s/abc123

and run the index action like normally

I currently have

```
        routes.MapRoute(null, "s/index/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
             );
```

but I'm kind of stuck as to where to go from here. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Edit: My full routeconfig class

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("sites/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(null, "s/index/{key}", new
        {
            controller = "S",
            action = "Index",
            key = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Site", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "Custom.Web.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

in my controller I have the actionresult index as

```
    public ActionResult Index(string Key)
    {
        return Redirect(workflow.RetrieveURL(Key));
    }
```

Comment: Could you please try the pattern `"s/{key}"`, also changing `id = UrlParameter.Optional`, to `key = UrlParameter.Optional`?

Comment: @AndreCalil unfortunately I still get a server error,
I'd also like to add that I'd like s/MyOtherAction to run as normal, but I just want when I go to http://dev.mywebsite.com/s/abc123 to run the index action with abc123 as the key

Comment: Could you provide the error details? Also, it would be nice to have the signature of `Home/Index` action. Do you have any other routing rule?

Comment: @AndreCalil I have added extra code as requested. Please take a look and let me know what you think. 
I keep getting the 404 error. 'page not found'

Comment: Well, your current route is wrong. `Controller` should be `Home` and I *think* that `Key` should be capitalized. However, if you put a breakpoint at `Index` action, is it ever hit?

Comment: @AndreCalil

When i type in the following

http://dev.mywebsite.com/s/index/abc123 it works as required, but I still get the 404 message when i type in http://dev.mywebsite.com/s/abc123

you meant to change controller = "S" to controller = "Home" right?

Comment: Yes, and your pattern should be `"s/{key}"` instead of `"s/index/{key}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after all our comments, the solution is:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "s/{Key}",
new {
  controller = "Home",
  action = "Index",
  Key = UrlParameter.Optional
});
```

Place this rule before all the others to give it preference